# MySQL issue with UPDATE numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a very simple UPDATE with PHP, like this:

```
$nlk = $lk + "1";
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET like = '".$nlk."' WHERE id = '".$cid."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

`$lk` is a the value gotten from the field `like`, which is default `0`.
`$cid` is a value from an `id` field, which is on `auto_increment`.

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'like = '1'
>   WHERE id = '45'' at line 1

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this (added ticks (`` ` ``) around the column name):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET `like` = '".$nlk."' WHERE id = '".$cid."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Better yet, don't use [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) as table/column names.

Answer (score 5):

like is a reserved word. You need to surround it with back-ticks

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET `like` = '".$nlk."' WHERE id = '".$cid."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3):

`like` is a reserved keyword. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) for a list of reserved keywords in mysql. **If you enclose your `like`-Column in backticks (`), the error should go away.**

Answer (score 1):

`like` is a MySQL keyword. It's most likely this is the case. Either try escaping the field name

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET `like` = '".$nlk."' WHERE id = '".$cid."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Or, if you're still getting the same error, change the field name to something else

Answer (score 0):

Like is a keyword in SQL. This could cause your error. Change your column name, or, at least, add the table name in front of your "like".

Answer (score 0):

because LIKE is a keyword. use backticks around like.

Answer (score 0):

like is a mysql [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

you have to put this column name in back quotes

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET `like` = '".$nlk."' WHERE id = '".$cid."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -2):

The hint is in your error message, near WHERE id = '45"

This query will probably run if replace the double quotation mark with a single.

-gz

My bad, I missed the leading single in front of the reserved word like, and was viewing with non-monospace font so the two singles at the end looked like a double. Dur.